# React using JQuery post+get data

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, reactjs, httprequest

I use this to get the `todos` from Django server:

```
getTodos(){
    $.ajax({url: "http://localhost:8000/todos/",
            success: function(data){
                this.setState({todos:data},function(){console.log(data)})}.bind(this),
            cache: false});
}
```

and this to post a new `todo` as well as update the state:

```
  handleAddTodo(title,text){
        $.post("http://localhost:8000/todos/",{title:title,text:text},this.getTodos());
    }
```

So the callback function `this.getTodos()` will fetch the new data from the server. But it seems the server side is not updated?[image]

In the picture, the first log is from the initial data fetch. The last is from the callback function.

Comment: What is your query here?

Comment: After I made the post, the server side should add a new todo, and then get request should return the new todos, but it still return the old version of todos, why is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think issue is with this line:

```
$.post("http://localhost:8000/todos/",{title:title,text:text},this.getTodos());
```

Here you need to pass a function that will trigger once post part will be successful, but you are not passing a function, passing a value returned by function by calling that using `()`. By this way this function will get called parallely with post call, check the network part you will see both the calls at the same time.

Either use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
$.post("http://localhost:8000/todos/",
       {title:title,text:text}, 
       () => {
           this.getTodos()
       }
);
```

Or write it like this:

```
$.post("http://localhost:8000/todos/",
       {title:title,text:text}, 
       this.getTodos
);
```

And bind `getTodos` method in the constructor:

```
this.getTodos = this.getTodos.bind(this);
```

Check the **[DOC](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)** for more details.